# Create a JSON per row of csv

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to figure out how to tweak my code so that it will write each row of a csv to its own json, which will then be posted (with how I want to try and loop through this, the json file being overwritten each time is no issue).

My code produces structured jsons as I need it to and formats everything to the correct data type, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to loop through this row wise.  I have another piece of code which can achieve this second aim, but all my attempts at combining them have failed so far.

Any suggestions of how I might loop through this code?

```
output = []
with open('Test3.csv') as csv_file:
    for a in csv.DictReader(csv_file):
        output.append({
            'OrderType': a['OrderType'],
            'OrderStatus': a['OrderStatus'],
            'OrderDateTime': a['OrderDateTime'],
            'SettlementDate': a['SettlementDate'],
            'MarketId': int(a['MarketId']),
            'OrderRoute': a['OrderRoute'],
            'OrderEntityType': a['OrderEntityType'],
            'SecurityId': a['SecurityId'],
            'CurrencyISOCode': a['CurrencyISOCode'],
            'Price': float(a['Price']),
            'TotalCommission': float(a['TotalCommission']),
            'SettlementStatus': a['SettlementStatus'],
            'QuantitySettled': float(a['QuantitySettled']),
            'SecurityOrderAllocations': {
                'Reference': a['Account Number'],
                'InvestmentCollectiveId': a['Account Number'],
                'NominalAmount': float(a['QuantitySettled']),
                'InvestmentAmount': float(a['InvestmentAmount']),
                'OpenNominal': float(a['QuantitySettled']),
                'SettlementCurrencyISOCode': 'USD',
                'SettlementAccountId': a['Account Number'],
                'OrderToSettlementExchangeRate': float('1'),
                'SettlementToPortfolioExchangeRate': float('1'),
                'OrderToPortfolioExchangeRate': float('1')
            }
        })

output_json = json.dumps(output)
with open ('Test.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(output_json)
```

Comment: You want each row to be written to a different JSON file, like `test1.json`, `test2.json`, etc.?

Comment: To clarify - is your goal to have each (currently appended) dictionary saved as its own json file?

Comment: @Barmar I'm happy to either have these written to individual files, or have them written to one file which constantly gets overwritten after posting - this code is currently set up to write one very long json with everything going out in one call, rather than individually.

Comment: If you overwrite one file, it will just contain the last row of the CSV, so why bother writing all the other lines in the first place?

Comment: @Barmar The aim would be to contain a POST command to an API inside the loop, so that after each json is created it is posted and then the next one is created and posted etc. until the bottom of the csv has been hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert each dict that you create from a CSV row to JSON, and write that to a file (or POST it to a URL, or whatever you want to do with it).

```
filenum = 1
with open('Test3.csv') as csv_file:
    for a in csv.DictReader(csv_file):
        json = json.dumps({
            'OrderType': a['OrderType'],
            'OrderStatus': a['OrderStatus'],
            'OrderDateTime': a['OrderDateTime'],
            'SettlementDate': a['SettlementDate'],
            'MarketId': int(a['MarketId']),
            'OrderRoute': a['OrderRoute'],
            'OrderEntityType': a['OrderEntityType'],
            'SecurityId': a['SecurityId'],
            'CurrencyISOCode': a['CurrencyISOCode'],
            'Price': float(a['Price']),
            'TotalCommission': float(a['TotalCommission']),
            'SettlementStatus': a['SettlementStatus'],
            'QuantitySettled': float(a['QuantitySettled']),
            'SecurityOrderAllocations': {
                'Reference': a['Account Number'],
                'InvestmentCollectiveId': a['Account Number'],
                'NominalAmount': float(a['QuantitySettled']),
                'InvestmentAmount': float(a['InvestmentAmount']),
                'OpenNominal': float(a['QuantitySettled']),
                'SettlementCurrencyISOCode': 'USD',
                'SettlementAccountId': a['Account Number'],
                'OrderToSettlementExchangeRate': float('1'),
                'SettlementToPortfolioExchangeRate': float('1'),
                'OrderToPortfolioExchangeRate': float('1')
            }
        })
        with open('Test' + str(filenum) + '.csv', 'w') as f:
            f.write(json)
    filenum += 1
```